# Dataframe row slicing is not consistent

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` variable called `data` with ~ 6 mil rows and I'd like to process it 50 rows at a time. I have the following code:

```
#Only 4001 for debugging purposes
for i in range(0,4001,50):
  print(str(i) + " - " + str(i+49))
  current_batch = data["text"].loc[i:(i+49)]
  print("Batch size: " + str(len(current_batch.tolist())))
```

However it seems the slices obtained are not 50 rows in length. In fact they seem to be random (although every time I re-run the program they stay consistent. The first one is always 34, then always 48 etc ...). Here is a sample output:

```
0 - 49
Batch size: 34
50
Batch size: 48
...
```

Is this an expected behavior from the `DataFrame` class?

Comment: Maybe your dataframe index has gaps? Try `iloc` instead of `loc`, to slice by position rather than by index.

Comment: I'm agree with @Arne. +1. Reset your index and retry your loop (or use iloc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

That's what happens when you use `loc`. And that's what happens when you use `iloc`:

[image]